# update countif formula for duplicates when adding new entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula, userform, vba

I need to create unique ID's in my workbook which need to be in format '01-01/' '01-02/' '02-01/'. This part of the ID reflects a category and is generated for each entry with vlookup. After the / needs to come a number representing the current occurrence of each category in the list. I get this number by using the countif formula for counting duplicates. Finally I create the ID by concatenating the root and the number.

```
column E (vlookup)   
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D13;Labels!$A$2:$B$20;2;FALSE);"na")
01-01/
01-01/
04-03/
01-04/
01-03/
01-03/

column F (countif)
=COUNTIF($E$2:E13;E13)
2
1
1
3
4
1


column G (concatenate)
01-01/2
01-02/1
03-02/1
01-01/3
01-01/4
04-03/1
```

The sheet these columns are in, is a sheet that collects data input from a user form. For each new entry I use a code that copies the formula of the previous row to the new record:

```
.Range("E" & lRow - 1 & ":I" & lRow - 1).copy
.Range("E" & lRow & ":I" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

This works fine except that the countif formula is not updated. If I have a new entry I get for instance:

```
01-03/  8   01-03/8
01-03/  8   01-03/8
```

while it should be 01-03/8 and 01-03/9.

Comment: Are you sure the macro doesnt change the recalculations to manual? Because that would result in this behaviour.

Comment: Why not extend your countif formula down before copying/pasting?

Comment: because when I extend the formula down, a new record generated by the user form will be registered in the row just below the extended formula range